# Display list of user email addresses in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to get a list of all users in meteor using Metor.methods

This is my code :
**server/main.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
  'createUser': function(){
    if (Meteor.users.find({}).count()===0) {
      for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
        let id = Accounts.createUser({
          email: Meteor.settings.ADMIN_USE,
          password: Meteor.settings.ADMIN_PASSWORD,
          profile: { firstName: Meteor.settings.ADMIN_FIRSTNAME, lastName: Meteor.settings.ADMIN_LASTNAME }
        });
       }
     }
   },

  'returnmail': function(){
    return Meteor.users.findOne().emails[0].address;
  }
});
```

then i call this function in another file called **Listusers.js**:

```
Template.ListUsers.helpers({
  email: function(){
    Meteor.call('returnmail');
  },
});
```

I'm trying to display the value of email using this code but it doesn't work

**Client/ListUsers.html**

```
<Template name="ListUsers">
  <input id="mail" type="text" value="{{email}}" />
</Template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems. I strongly recommend you go through [the tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) at least. The [Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/) ebook is also invaluable. One of the first steps in understanding Meteor is moving from a traditional XHR request-response model to publish-subscribe.

1. Your `email` helper needs to `return` a value.
2. `Meteor.call()` doesn't return anything. Normally you use it with a callback that gives you an error status and the result. However you can't use that in a helper unless you use a *Session variable* or a *promise* because the return value from the call is at the wrong context level.
3. Your `returnmail` method is only returning a single email address from `findOne()` and not any specific one either, just a quasi-random one (you can't guarantee which document `findOne()` is going to return!)
4. You're creating 5 identical users with the same email address and password. 2-5 are going to fail because of a uniqueness constraint on the email field.

Now on to the solution.

1. On the server, *publish* the *Users* collection including only the emails field (which is an array of objects)
2. On the client, *subscribe* to that publication.
3. On the client, iterate over the users collection and get the email address from a helper.

server:

```
Meteor.publish('allEmails',function(){
  // you should restrict this publication to only be available to admin users
  return Meteor.users.find({},{fields: { emails: 1 }});
});
```

client js:

```
Meteor.subscribe('allEmails');

Template.ListUsers.helpers({
  allUsers(){ return Meteor.users.find({}); },
  email(){ return this.emails[0].address; }
});
```

client html:

```
<Template name="ListUsers">
  {{#each allUsers}}
    <input id="mail" type="text" value="{{email}}" />
  {{/each}}
</Template>
```